# Redirect based on part of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How do I do an apache redirect to a startic splash page based on a dynamic url.  Part of the url is always static. For example, http://buy.domain.com/product/product1-name-here
What do I need to do if I want to redirected everything that comes in http://buy.domain.com/product/* to a certain page?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this simple rule in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^product/.*$ /yourSplashPage? [R,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file, create an Apache RewriteRule to selectively choose links based on a regular expression.

```
RewriteRule ^product/.*$ /certainPage.html?
```